# When to use and not to use inverse navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework, data-modeling

It is obvious when to use a navigation property. But when should I use a inverse navigational property and when should I not use a inverse navigational property?

Should I always use a inverse navigation property when I use a navigation property to create a bi-directional relation?

Are there any guiding principles?

Answer (score 5):

My guiding principle is to strive to keep things simple. I don't use them until I *need* them. :) Just like any other public member or method, (or any code for that matter) it should only exist if that existence is justified.

The presence of an inverse property indicates that I may treat that entity as a top-level and need to be able to refer to it's related entity. For example, a Customer contains Orders, so the question is should an Order reference back to it's Customer?

If I can query orders (irrespective of Customer) and want to be able to access customer information in those queries then it is beneficial to have an inverse property.

```
var orderDetails = context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDate == DateTime.Today)
    .Select(o => new 
    {
        o.OrderId,
        o.OrderNumber,
        CustomerName = o.Customer.Name
    }).ToList();
```

As opposed to joining customer and order in a query to gain access to both customer and order details via a one-directional reference. (I tried writing an example from memory, but it got too ugly too fast. :D )

Where it doesn't make sense is to "always" have bi-directional references. For instance when you have something like an Address and an AddressType. AddressType will never need to know about a list of addresses of that type, and even if you did want to query that detail, it is easy enough to filter via the single-direction reference. It makes sense that Address (relative to the address type) is the top-level reference, where-as it makes sense that you may want to reference orders from a customer, or customer from an order.

Answer (score 2):

They do not affect the generated sql. So from the point of view of database structure this is not important.

But when you are querying data from database by linq you can use that properties in "where" and "include" statements. So it gives you more options to create a query.

I'm almost always specifica inverse navigation property.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when having bi-directional navigation properties is that it can lead to recursive infinite loops when serializing, which is why I decorate the inverse navigation property with the `[JsonIgnore]` property.

Comment: While it does not affect the generated SQL it does have an effect when it comes to domain-driven design (DDD).